# Why is my nav bar overlaying Fancybox and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, browser, fancybox

I've recently installed a photo gallery WordPress plugin on my school's website, and everything seems to be working except one thing: the navigation bar is overlaying images:

[image]

Everything seems to work in other themes.

Where and how can I fix this?

I'm running the latest version of Iceweasel that is in Debian's repos, but I've checked with other browsers too.

Comment: just increase the z-index of light box as compare to navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
 #fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
    outline: none;
    display: none;}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm new to WordPress. Not sure where I'm supposed to place that. I'll try some file that gets included into every page I guess.

Comment: http://petagimnazija.hr/wp/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
at line no 58

Comment: I appended `999` to every Fancybox `z-index`, because your original solution still left some elements not covered by the overlay, but thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: thanks i have one more solution if you wana try just set z-index:99 in .menu1 class.(or any no less then 1100 coz your light box have z-index:1100)